# Spring doesn't return JSON in full

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am using spring boot and @PostMapping trying to return a POJO that contains 1 Multipart file and some String. When i look at Postman i only see half of the Multipart object. File is 3kb. I don't get any errors. When i return the multipart variable null other variables in JSON are being shown in response so they are not empty.  How can i return all of the JSON?

```
public class foo{
    public MultipartFile dataFile;
    
    public String project;
    
    public Boolean extract;

    ... getter - setter - constructor
}
```

I send it like

```
@PostMapping
public foo route(@RequestParam("dataFile") MultipartFile dataFile, ... ) {

 ...
    return fooObject;
}
```

Response

```
{
    "dataFile": {
        "name": "dataFile",
        "bytes":"MIKCAQYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIKB8jCCge4CA... (half of the file)
```

Comment: What is the value of the header `Content-type` sent by your server ?

Comment: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: How do you create your `MultipartFile` ?

Comment: @RequestParam("foo") MultipartFile foo then insert to the object constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I thought, the `MultipartFile` is used to upload object, not to download it. As stated in the Javadoc:

> A representation of an uploaded file received in a multipart request.

Which means, it is great for upload, but that is not the case for download.

The easiest way (and the most straightforward) would be to change the `MultipartFile` to a `byte[]` and send that to the client.

Here is an example:

```
public Foo getFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
    return new Foo(bytes, "project");
}
```